# WiFi on HP Pavilion dv6 stopped working after update to 11.10

Tags: 11.10, wireless, hp, dv6

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and Windows 7 on my HP Pavilion dv6. Before the 11.10 update, everything was working perfectly, but after I updated, I've never been able to use the WiFi with Ubuntu. For the most part, I've just stuck to Windows and when I've needed to use Ubuntu, I've just been plugging in a network cable. The additional drivers are installed and it says they're active, but the wireless isn't working. What can I do to find the problem?

Comment: It would help to know what your wireless hardware is. Please post the output of "sudo lspci -v" (just the section for the wireless card).

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a long shot but I had the same issue on my DV6 with 11.10 until I noticed that I had hit the F12 key which effectively disables the wireless connectivity.
Hit F12 to turn it back on.   Sorry if this is bleedin' obvious but it had me going for while